# A NULL check in Twig Template is not working which leads to an error (very strange behavior)

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I’m currently facing a very strange problem in a Twig template (Symfony v2.8.9; Twig v1.24.1). The basic outline is: I’m trying to overwrite a block in a child template when a specific condition is met.

Here’s a snippet of my template:

```
{% extends "@App/search/resultList.html.twig" %}

{% if category.teaser %}
  {% block description %}{{category.teaser.doSomething()}}{% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

This code leads to the following error:

> Impossible to invoke a method ("doSomething") on a null variable in @App/search/categoryResult.html.twig

The teaser property of the category indeed is null, which is okay and what the check is for.

I also tried an explicit `{% if category.teaser is not null %}` which also didn’t work and resulted in the same error.

Now for the really weird part (or maybe I’m just not seeing it why this wouldn’t be weird):

If I change the code to

```
{% block description %}
  {% if category.teaser %}
    {{category.teaser.doSomething()}}
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

it works as intended (mostly, at least, because the parent block will always be overwritten).

**This error seems to happen only in the Symfony dev environment.**

It seems:

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            true
    strict_variables: true
```

has something to do with it, which explains the dev environment only. If both values are set to `false` it works correctly.

Has anybody ever encountered a problem like this and solved it? Any help in solving this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: my configs are always set up like `debug: "%kernel.debug%"` and `strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"`, and never had this problem. Also I never use `()` in twig

Comment: my config is also `"%kernel.debug%"` for both values (which will result in true for the symfony dev controller). i used the explicit values for better understanding. the `()`are there to indicate a function call (which uses parameters in the original code) instead of parameter access via automatic getter usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it is not possible to conditionally override a block in twig, see also **[How can I conditionally override a TWIG layout block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738772/how-can-i-conditionally-override-a-twig-layout-block)**

Answer (score -2):

You have done the best practice by testing whether the variable is null or not.
In many other languages you can’t do something on a null. You can use the `dump()` function to check your variables.